# Query Debug Mode Information Via Apex

Tags: apex, debug

Is there any way to Query the [Debug Mode](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aura_debug_mode.htm&type=5) Information? I am looking to get information about all the users for whom debug mode has been enabled via apex?

if there is any other way than apex, i would like to know that as well apart from the Standard UI route.

Answer (score 0):

There is a field on the [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) object called `UserPreferencesUserDebugModePref` that stores this information that you can leverage in a query in Apex.

> **When true, the Lightning Component framework executes in debug mode
> for the user**. Corresponds to the Debug Mode checkbox on the Advanced
> User Details page of personal settings in the user interface.